# composer.phar very slow and not completing install or update

Tags: php, composer-php

I must use composer on my own nas server for a php web project.
Composer is available there on my nas, i downloaded the newest version, but if I call install or update, it need a long time and then composer does nothing anymore (no furthed progress, it stucks on "writing to cache" or "reading from cache").

Eatings for a few hours:

```
CPU: 0 - 19%
HDD: 70%!
RAM: 70 - 80%
```

... but no progress. Composer looks like he paused and do nothing. You will see the composer output logfile soon.

I would like to show you my composer.json:

```
    {
        "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
        "license": "MIT",
        "type": "project",
        "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
        "autoload": {
            "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
        },
        "require": {
            "php": ">=5.3.3",
            "symfony/symfony": "~2.4",
            "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
            "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
            "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
            "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
            "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
            "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
            "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
            "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
            "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
            "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
            "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
            "doctrine/data-fixtures" : "dev-master",
            "raveren/kint": "@dev",
            "cg/kint-bundle": "dev-master"
        },
        "scripts": {
            "post-install-cmd": [
                "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
                "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
                "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
                "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
                "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
            ],
            "post-update-cmd": [
                "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
                "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
                "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
                "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
                "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
            ]
        },
        "config": {
            "bin-dir": "bin"
        },
        "minimum-stability": "dev",
        "extra": {
            "symfony-app-dir": "app",
            "symfony-web-dir": "web",
            "incenteev-parameters": {
                "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
            },
            "branch-alias": {
                "dev-master": "2.4-dev"
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's my call to start composer:

```
php composer.phar update --prefer-dist -vvv --profile >./composer.log.txt
```

He run a long time and after some "hours" (!!) i killed it with CTRL + C. 
It is no problem, if composer would need a long time, maybe some hours, but he should finish his work at least.
I have to tell something about the nas. It is not powerful. 1.2 GHz, 128 MB RAM. So this could be a big problem for running composer?

xdebug is deactivated.

Here's the composer log output, composer.log.txt:

```
[0.9MB/0.11s] Reading ./composer.json
[0.9MB/0.20s] Loading config file ./composer.json
[0.9MB/0.30s] Executing command (CWD): git describe --exact-match --tags
[1.0MB/0.68s] Executing command (CWD): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
[1.6MB/1.41s] Loading composer repositories with package information
[1.7MB/1.50s] Downloading https://packagist.org/packages.json
[1.7MB/1.71s] Writing /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/packages.json into cache
[1.7MB/1.78s] Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
[1.7MB/1.83s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-active.json from cache
[4.1MB/2.14s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-archived.json from cache
[9.2MB/2.78s] Downloading https://packagist.org/p/provider-latest$27f0883b66e23851d98d77f3f2d38b260f97886ecaef58ba5270dc855617f31d.json
[13.9MB/3.66s] Writing /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-latest.json into cache
[12.6MB/3.95s] Downloading https://packagist.org/p/provider-stale$8f6a69f2604637ea5a49e850799189ce535eef932daa4cd3a975876dfde82ece.json
[16.6MB/4.78s] Writing /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-stale.json into cache
[15.1MB/5.18s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-doctrine$data-fixtures.json from cache
[15.1MB/5.24s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-doctrine$doctrine-fixtures-bundle.json from cache
[15.2MB/5.38s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-jdorn$sql-formatter.json from cache
[15.2MB/5.41s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-psr$log.json from cache
[15.2MB/5.43s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-twig$twig.json from cache
[15.4MB/5.55s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-doctrine$lexer.json from cache
[15.5MB/5.56s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-doctrine$annotations.json from cache
[15.5MB/5.59s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-doctrine$collections.json from cache
[15.5MB/5.61s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-doctrine$cache.json from cache
[15.6MB/5.64s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-doctrine$inflector.json from cache
[15.6MB/5.66s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-doctrine$common.json from cache
[15.9MB/5.86s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-doctrine$dbal.json from cache
[16.4MB/6.42s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$doctrine-bridge.json from cache
[23.3MB/13.20s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$framework-bundle.json from cache
[24.9MB/14.40s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-doctrine$doctrine-bundle.json from cache
[25.1MB/14.65s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$config.json from cache
[25.5MB/15.39s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$http-kernel.json from cache
[27.9MB/16.32s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$filesystem.json from cache
[28.3MB/16.68s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$routing.json from cache
[29.0MB/17.45s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$stopwatch.json from cache
[29.3MB/17.73s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$translation.json from cache
[29.8MB/18.24s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$dependency-injection.json from cache
[30.4MB/18.83s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$event-dispatcher.json from cache
[31.0MB/19.70s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$templating.json from cache
[31.5MB/20.71s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$http-foundation.json from cache
[31.9MB/21.23s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$security-core.json from cache
[32.6MB/21.92s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$security-csrf.json from cache
[33.5MB/23.54s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$debug.json from cache
[33.2MB/26.25s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-doctrine$doctrine-cache-bundle.json from cache
[33.3MB/26.36s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$security.json from cache
[34.2MB/28.09s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$process.json from cache
[34.6MB/28.49s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-kriswallsmith$assetic.json from cache
[34.9MB/28.84s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$options-resolver.json from cache
[35.2MB/29.16s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-knplabs$gaufrette.json from cache
[35.4MB/29.46s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$finder.json from cache
[35.8MB/30.25s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$assetic-bundle.json from cache
[36.5MB/36.41s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$console.json from cache
[37.0MB/36.86s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-doctrine$orm.json from cache
[37.7MB/37.56s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-doctrine$instantiator.json from cache
[37.7MB/37.63s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-twig$extensions.json from cache
[37.8MB/37.67s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-swiftmailer$swiftmailer.json from cache
[37.9MB/37.76s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$swiftmailer-bridge.json from cache
[38.4MB/38.22s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$swiftmailer-bundle.json from cache
[38.8MB/38.72s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-sensio$distribution-bundle.json from cache
[39.1MB/39.19s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$class-loader.json from cache
[39.6MB/39.66s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$form.json from cache
[40.5MB/40.43s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$validator.json from cache
[41.4MB/41.43s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$yaml.json from cache
[42.9MB/42.52s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-sensiolabs$security-checker.json from cache
[42.9MB/42.69s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$property-access.json from cache
[43.2MB/42.96s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$locale.json from cache
[43.7MB/43.77s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$intl.json from cache
[44.6MB/44.70s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$icu.json from cache
[44.2MB/45.34s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-sensio$generator-bundle.json from cache
[44.6MB/45.93s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$doctrine-bundle.json from cache
[44.6MB/46.20s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-incenteev$composer-parameter-handler.json from cache
[44.6MB/46.39s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$symfony.json from cache
[44.7MB/46.55s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-monolog$monolog.json from cache
[44.9MB/47.06s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$monolog-bridge.json from cache
[45.5MB/47.61s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$monolog-bundle.json from cache
[45.9MB/48.94s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-sensio$framework-extra-bundle.json from cache
[46.2MB/49.30s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-raveren$kint.json from cache
[46.3MB/49.32s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-cg$kint-bundle.json from cache
[46.3MB/49.34s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$framework-standard-edition.json from cache
[49.3MB/50.39s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-jms$security-extra-bundle.json from cache
[49.4MB/50.49s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-jms$di-extra-bundle.json from cache
[49.6MB/50.67s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$security-bundle.json from cache
[50.3MB/51.34s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-jms$metadata.json from cache
[50.4MB/51.39s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-jms$aop-bundle.json from cache
[50.5MB/52.92s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-jms$cg.json from cache
[50.5MB/53.17s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-jms$parser-lib.json from cache
[50.5MB/53.25s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-phpoption$phpoption.json from cache
[56.5MB/58.98s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$browser-kit.json from cache
[57.2MB/62.36s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$css-selector.json from cache
[57.6MB/63.24s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$dom-crawler.json from cache
[58.1MB/64.05s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$propel1-bridge.json from cache
[58.6MB/64.73s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$serializer.json from cache
[59.0MB/67.62s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$twig-bridge.json from cache
[60.1MB/68.66s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$twig-bundle.json from cache
[60.7MB/69.85s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$web-profiler-bundle.json from cache
[61.6MB/73.41s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$proxy-manager-bridge.json from cache
[61.9MB/74.49s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$expression-language.json from cache
[62.0MB/75.01s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$security-acl.json from cache
[62.3MB/87.77s] Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$security-http.json from cache
[86.6MB/299.81s] Downloading http://packagist.org/p/symfony/doctrine-abstract-bundle$557a1f9a31777860331e98ff2877ea8d8caf0d14519abf3d20cba65cf3ad4fc0.json
[87.1MB/300.38s] Writing /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$doctrine-abstract-bundle.json into cache
```

No further progress at "Writing /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$doctrine-abstract-bundle.json into cache" for 7 hours. But the HDD was working a lot.

I tried again for a very long time and then composer stucked on "Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$doctrine-abstract-bundle.json from cache".

Do you know what to do to fix this?
I would be glad about every advice. Thank you.

Comment: It seems like Composer is or was experiencing difficulties with it's web infrastructure, so this likely is a temporary problem.

Comment: So you think this has nothing to do with my configuration or my NAS server? My internet connection is quite good and i tried to update on two days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reviewing your hardware details, the situation is clear: 128 MB of RAM is not enough!

I have seen reports for Composer using as much as 4 GB in more extreme cases, and easily up to 1 GB regularly. Your NAS probably is busy swapping and will eventually finish given enough time, but this will probably take days if not weeks.

Don't run Composer on underpowered hardware. Try to run it on a machine that is able to give plenty of RAM. Then grab all the files downloaded and put them on your NAS to run the application.

Additionally, you make things worse by running an update, and with "minimum-stability:dev". Running the update forces Composer to download plenty of package info about all possible versions that it might be updating to. Running with dev stability increases the amount of versions considerably.

I think that Composer MIGHT be able to simply run `install` (it will require less RAM because it simply has to download all the packages mentioned in the `composer.lock`), but 128 MB is probably way too low to succeed.

Comment: Thanks for your info! I have linux installed on my working machine with i5 and 8 GB of ram. Is it possible to run composer there and let composer put the downloaded files DIRECTLY to my nas (a samba drive is mounted)? I would like to avoid copying all the files and would like to let the program save the files directly to the NAS.

Comment: Ideas:

1) Maybe i can set the DESTINATION PATH while initializing the composer project on my local machine?

    composer create-project [PACKAGE] [DESTINATION PATH] [--FLAGS]
 
2) Another idea: Use git (it's available on my NAS) and let composer create the .lock file on my working machine. Then commit this file. On the NAS, checkout this file and run composer install.

Which solution would you pursue? Do you have another ideas?

Comment: I would to post some news. I think it's not possible to store the files from composer install command directly on a nas server. but i got a solution. your tip to run composer on a power machine was perfect. i executed composer update locally. then i copied the composer.lock to my nas server and executed composer install there and it just worked like a charm. that is ok for me. thank you very much.